# Maven and Archetype

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-archetype

Is it possible to create own own project structure ( Archetype) i also like to add some dynamic files to be created.

What steps involved to create it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Maven Archetype Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/) to do this. You could use the [`create-from-project`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html) goal to create an archetype from an existing project and then modify this  archetype so it fits your needs. You will find all details on the [project site](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [tutorial on maven archetypes](http://marosmars.weebly.com/1/post/2014/02/maven-archetype-tutorial.html). This tutorial builds an archetype from the ground for Maven 3.x and demonstrates:

- required / optional properties
- dynamic files
- integration tests
- archetype usage

There is also [finished code for the tutorial archetype](https://github.com/marosmars/maven-library-archetype) on github: